# How can I pull a remote repository with GitPython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am trying to find the way to pull a git repository using gitPython.
So far this is what I have taken from the official docs [here](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#handling-remotes).

```
test_remote = repo.create_remote('test', 'git@server:repo.git')
repo.delete_remote(test_remote) # create and delete remotes
origin = repo.remotes.origin    # get default remote by name
origin.refs                     # local remote references
o = origin.rename('new_origin') # rename remotes
o.fetch()                       # fetch, pull and push from and to the remote
o.pull()
o.push()
```

The fact is that I want to access the repo.remotes.origin to do a pull withouth renaming it's origin (origin.rename)
How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I managed this by getting the repo name directly:

```
 repo = git.Repo('repo_path')
 o = repo.remotes.origin
 o.pull()
```

Comment: `git.Repo(repo_dir).remotes[remote].pull()` if your remote is a string

Comment: `git.Repo(repo_dir).remotes.origin.pull(options)`, where, for example `options='--tags'`

Comment: `repo = git.Repo(localpath_to_repo_dir)  
repo.remotes.origin.pull(branch_name)`
if you want to pull from a branch by name

Comment: How to force pull using this method ?

Comment: In case somebody is interested, that command displayed a lot of "trash"(it wasn't useful for me at least) on the screen. The way of getting around it is to assign the result to `_`. Something like this: `_ = Repo(folder_name).remotes.origin.pull()`

Comment: I am also having some issues regarding GitPython. Could you please clarify to me how can I fetch/pull from the repository with the authentication? All the methods you have suggested does not take into account that some repositories may need to username and password

Answer (score 11):

As the accepted answer says it's possible to use `repo.remotes.origin.pull()`, but the drawback is that it hides the real error messages into it's own generic errors. For example when DNS resolution doesn't work, then `repo.remotes.origin.pull()` shows the following error message:

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: 'Error when fetching: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
' returned with exit code 2
```

On the other hand [using git commands with GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly) like `repo.git.pull()` shows the real error:

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: 'git pull' returned with exit code 1
stderr: 'ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.'
```

Answer (score 11):

Hope you are looking for this :

```
import git
g = git.Git('git-repo')
g.pull('origin','branch-name')
```

Pulls latest commits for the given repository and branch.

Comment: Work for me :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This also works if you want to pull directly from a URL

Answer (score 5):

git.Git module from [Akhil Singhal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9310437/akhil-singhal) s' answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48681912/11284684) still works, but has been [renamed](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html?highlight=Git%20has%20been%20moved%20to%20cmd#git) to [git.cmd.Git](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=Cmd#module-git.cmd), e.g.:

```
import git 
# pull from remote origin to the current working dir:
git.cmd.Git().pull('https://github.com/User/repo','master')
```

Comment: That change you reffer to has been made over 15 years ago..