# Python github Pull using username and password

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, github

I am making an app in python for git pull using username and password. I ve already cloned github repository in local. Now i want to pull every time using python by different user, for that they need to enter every time username and password. For example if i apply github commands on terminal:

```
git pull origin master
```

it asks username and password (which is i am currently looking how to do in python) which it pulls all recent commits.

[image]

I am following that tutorial but it says to configure which means (if i am not wrong) will save the all infos. Moreover it creates a new repo whereas my repo already exists as i already did clone.
Tutorial:

https://www.devdungeon.com/content/working-git-repositories-python

This post i also followed:

[How can I pull a remote repository with GitPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166595/how-can-i-pull-a-remote-repository-with-gitpython)

Here is on my local Github directory which i cloned through terminal:

[[image]][

On website:

[image]

Sorry for bad English. I need help to understand this phenomena.

Comment: You should consider using [SSH authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh).

Comment: @KlausD. Not python did u mean?

Comment: Python is unrelated to the underlying git authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set your username and password in your .git/config or ~/.git-credentials file for the repository. Here's a link that helped me with a couple of ways to do it.

https://www.shellhacks.com/git-config-username-password-store-credentials/

Comment: Thanks bt i was able to succeed after exploring whole week. :)