# GitPython regularly fetch and pull all the changes from the gitlab repository with authentication

Tags: python, git, github, gitlab

I am using GitPython library:
https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

I could not find a way how to achieve what I want.

I want to be create an executable that would simply run `git fetch` and `git pull` commands and update the repository if needed. I need that because once I give the Raspberry PI to the client, I will no longer have physical access to it hence I want to ensure that the client can still get all the updates from my repository.

For now, I am just learning about GitPython and simply trying to commit and push via python using the following script:

```
import git


full_local_path "my_project_path"

remote = f"https://my_git_username:my_git_password@xxx-gitlab.xxxxxxx.lt/some-account/some-repo.git"
repo = git.Repo(full_local_path)


repo.index.commit("Some commit message")
origin = repo.remote(name="origin")
origin.push()
```

If I run the script on the computer that uses SSH key to authenticate ( no need to input username and password), the script will work without any issues.

However, what if I am running this script on the machine that does not have SSH key, How can I get this to work? Can I pass as a parameter my username and password ?

The error that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/Auto_Update.py", line 11, in <module>
    origin.push()
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/remote.py", line 1117, in push
    return self._get_push_info(proc, progress, kill_after_timeout=kill_after_timeout)
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/remote.py", line 926, in _get_push_info
    proc.wait(stderr=stderr_text)
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 602, in wait
    raise GitCommandError(remove_password_if_present(self.args), status, errstr)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git push --porcelain -- origin
  stderr: 'fatal: could not read Username for 'https://xxx-gitlab.xxxxxxx.lt': No such device or address'
```

For some reason, it does not allow me to authenticate even though the username and password are correct. Could someone help me understand how I can do that? I have tried reading the documentation but there is no clear answer.

I have found relevant stackoverflow post:
[How can I pull a remote repository with GitPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166595/how-can-i-pull-a-remote-repository-with-gitpython)

but this does not take into account authentication (username and password for the git account).